# Lodash find and keep index of items in an array

Tags: javascript, grouping, lodash

I am trying to find, group and keep indices of keywords in an array and store it as an object.

So say I have an object like so:

```
{
  "foo": ["bar", "bazz"],
  "boo": ["far", "fuzz"]
}
```

And I have a sentence like so:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit bar, consectetur adipiscing bazz. Nam luctus fringilla bazz. Suspendisse mauris far, aliquam in far nec, placerat quis leo. fuzz fuzz,

I wanted an output like so:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {"bar": [22]},
    {"bazz": [50, 77]}
  ],
  "boo": [
    {"far": [102, 118]},
    {"fuzz": [146, 151]}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to highlight the text as well as keep it categorized.

Comment: So, have you tried using `String.indexOf` with the second argument until you get -1 ?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are the numbers in your wanted output? What is the significance of "foo" and "boo"? Where is your code? What do you mean with highlighting? Are you talking about HTML, CSS? Do you know there are many questions on HTML text highlighting already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find indexes, you can use the following code

```
const a =
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit bar, consectetur adipiscing bazz. Nam luctus fringilla bazz. Suspendisse mauris far, aliquam in far nec, placerat quis leo. fuzz fuzz,";

const b = {
  foo: ["bar", "bazz"],
  boo: ["far", "fuzz"]
};

function groupAndFindIndexes(text, groups) {
  return Object.keys(b).reduce((store, id) => {
    store[id] = b[id].map(word => {
      const reg = new RegExp(word, "g");
      const items = [];
      let find = reg.exec(a);
      while (find) {
        items.push(find.index);
        find = reg.exec(a);
      }
      return { [word]: items };
    });
    return store;
  }, {});
}

const result = groupAndFindIndexes(a, b);
```

Result is:

```js
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": [22]
    },
    {
      "bazz": [50, 77]
    }
  ],
  "boo": [
    {
      "far": [102, 118]
    },
    {
      "fuzz": [146, 151]
    }
  ]
}
```